# mysql JOINS query

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables, `usersonline`, `mobsters`, and `gangs`.

I'm trying to create a query for the ONLINE USERS page that will run through the records in the `usersonline` table, linking the IDs to the relevant record in the `mobsters` table. If the mobster is in a gang, I want it to also grab the record from the `gangs` table.

Here is my query so far (this doesn't work):

```
SELECT m.*, g.* FROM usersonline u 
   INNER JOIN mobsters m ON u.userID = m.id 
      JOIN gangs g ON g.id = m.gang 
         ORDER BY u.timestamp DESC
```

What kind of JOINs should I be using? Is this query even correct?

The `gang` table is optional but it should always have a record in the `mobsters` that relates to the `usersonline`.

Note: My actual query doesn't grab all fields from each table, just did it this way for simplification.

Comment: Did you run it? What did it return? What was wrong with that? A shot in the dark, but try adding `LEFT OUTER` to `JOIN gangs` and verify the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [`LEFT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) Join on the Gangs table since "The gang table is optional"

e.g.

```
SELECT m.*, g.* FROM usersonline u 
   INNER JOIN mobsters m ON u.userID = m.id 
      LEFT JOIN gangs g ON g.id = m.gang 
         ORDER BY u.timestamp DESC
```